# Odd sized CPVC - fittings will not go on

Tags: water

Water system installed circa 2010/2011, with CPVC. We have since had some issues to be addressed.

New CPVC fittings WILL NOT WORK.  The outside diameter of the old CPVC is larger than the fittings, no matter if CPVC, sharkbite or other types of fittings.  I took a piece of the old CPVC to both Home Depot and to a large plumbing supply place.  Home Depot scanned the bar code and came up with "CPVC" with a couple of additional letters on the end, and made an "informed guess" that it was an older type of CPVC that is no longer in use.  Markings include "3/4" SCPI", but that is all I can access from the part I have.

Am I going to have to replace all of the hot water lines in order to connect things back up?

Comment: Did some googling, but did not find much about what fittings to use.  One link was for machinist site.  Would ask a plumber or two, they have probably done this type of work before and should know the right fittings to use.  Some big stores might carry all fittings for certain pipes, but would not stock all types, and their knowledge might not be complete of non stock.

Comment: Can you find more markings...?  This sounds like piping that was made to a different SDR than current CPVC...

Comment: Is the pipe white or kinda yellowish.    I have few sticks of 3/4" white with "cpvc" markings that uses normal pvc fittings.   I found it for potable water use years ago.

Comment: One fitting that should work for straight pipe to pipe joint is the rubber type hose with champs, like a short radiator hose.  If no other fitting can be found, would only need to replace short runs instead of whole house.